# Extract area from high resolution netcdf file python

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to extract an area from a netcdf file by longitude and latitude.
However the resolution is much higher than 1x1 degree.
How would you extract an area then, e.g. lon: 30-80 and lat: 30-40.
The file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zX-qYBdXT_GuktC81NoQz9xSxSzM-CTJ

Keys and shapes are as follows:

```
odict_keys(['crs', 'lat', 'lon', 'Band1'])
crs ()
lat (25827,)
lon (35178,)
Band1 (25827, 35178)
```

I have tried this, but with the high resolution, it doesn't refer to the actual longitude/langitude.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = path + '20180801-ESACCI-L3S_FIRE-BA-MODIS-AREA_3-fv5.1-JD.nc'
fh = Dataset(file)
longitude = fh.variables['lon'][:]
latitude = fh.variables['lat'][:]
band1 = fh.variables['Band1'][:30:80,30:40]
```

Comment: you're not far off, I think just the indexing in `fh.variables['Band1'][:30:80,30:40]` does not do what you expect... `[30:80,30:40]` would be index ranges, not ranges of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have `variables(dimensions): ..., int16 Band1(lat,lon)`, you could apply `np.where` to variables `lat` and `lon` to find the appropriate indices and then select the according `Band1` data as `sel_band1`:

```py
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

file = '20180801-ESACCI-L3S_FIRE-BA-MODIS-AREA_3-fv5.1-JD.nc'

with Dataset(file) as nc_obj:
    lat = nc_obj.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = nc_obj.variables['lon'][:]
    sel_lat, sel_lon = [30, 40], [30, 80]
    sel_lat_idx = np.where((lat >= sel_lat[0]) & (lat <= sel_lat[1]))
    sel_lon_idx = np.where((lon >= sel_lon[0]) & (lon <= sel_lon[1]))
    sel_band1 = nc_obj.variables['Band1'][:][np.ix_(sel_lat_idx[0], sel_lon_idx[0])]
```

note that `np.where` applied to `lat` and `lon` returns 1D index arrays. Use `np.ix_` to apply them to the 2D data in `Band1`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) for more info.